# htaccess and httpd.conf configuraion to enable codeigniter working on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 and I have complete requirements(apache,mysql and php5) for running php projects. Projects which are not in codeigniter are working well. Within codeigniter , when I load the project  the default controller loads the index_view but when I click to other controllers; they  wont work with error  and display error

### Not Found The requested URL /academic/login was not found on this server.

I realized that the .htaccess wont work; then the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file is empty
 I would like to request a sample of basic configuration of httpd.conf file so that my htaccess file can work. If any suggestion that can help me to arrive at some results would be appreciated. Thanks.
 My httaccess is given below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(platform(/index)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|academic) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/academic/$1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce NO www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

###

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

```
# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This trusty one has never done me wrong:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /academic/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/ [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: +1 but `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` is unnecessary. If someone supplies an invalid path, it will go through index.php anyway (with the combination of rules you have before that, at least).

Comment: Thanks, I realized that my htaccess from windows works correctly with this  `RewriteBase /academic/` in ubuntu 12.04 but  to work in ubuntu ; there are some other configurations: `a2enmod rewrite`  command, apache2 configuration file `httpd.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` where AllowOverride All replace AllowOverride None. Thanks.